# Has anyone see error global_output_type with cuml RAPIDS?

Tags: python, rapids

I am new to RAPIDS, and just tried to replicate a logisticregression model previously with sklearn, but now with cuml, but it the LogisticRegression() call does not work.

```
from cuml.linear_model import LogisticRegression, LinearRegression
ols_cuml=LogisticRegression(penalty='l2')

ols_cuml.fit(X,y)
```

I get the following error:

[python-error with cuml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEwtL.png)

the LinearRegression() load statement also gets the same error. Not sure why this is happeding considering cudf(Pandas for CUDA) loads well, and can operate on gpu dataframes.

Comment: Hi alf, welcome on SO. Do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

The above error that you mentioned generally happens if the build or python setup runs into errors.

I am using cuml-0.15 (nightly release) and dont see the same error as the one you mentioned above.
Try installing cuml from the command provided here : https://rapids.ai/start.html

The one that I used is : `conda install -c rapidsai-nightly -c nvidia -c conda-forge \ -c defaults cuml=0.15 python=3.7 cudatoolkit=10.2`